# PowerMock won't mock static method to throw an Exception in a Spring-Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, powermockito

I realize there are many many very similar questions. I've been through all of them and I still cannot make my code work.

I have a service defined in my Spring-Boot application, just like this:

```
@Service
public class FileStorageService {
    private final Path fileStorageLocation;

    @Autowired
    public FileStorageService(final FileStorageProperties fileStorageProperties) {
            //FileStorageProperties is a very simple class that right now just holds one String value
            this.fileStorageLocation = Paths.get(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir())
                .toAbsolutePath()
                .normalize();

        try {
            Files.createDirectories(fileStorageLocation);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // FileStorageException is my custom, runtime exception
            throw new FileStorageException("Failed to create directory for stored files", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to test scenario, when directory creation fails and thus I need to mock method Files.createDirectories(). My test class looks like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Files.class})
public class FileStorageServiceTest {
    private static final String UPLOAD_DIR = "uploadDir";

    @Test(expected = FileStorageException.class)
    public void some_test() throws IOException {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Files.createDirectories(Mockito.any())).thenThrow(new IOException());

        new FileStorageService(createFileStorageProperties());
    }

    private FileStorageProperties createFileStorageProperties() {
        final FileStorageProperties fileStorageProperties = new FileStorageProperties();
        fileStorageProperties.setUploadDir(UPLOAD_DIR);
        return fileStorageProperties;
    }
}
```

I believe I followed every step from tutorials and questions I've read.
I use:

1. @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class),
2. @PrepareForTest({Files.class}),
3. PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class),
4. and PowerMockito.when(Files.createDirectories(Mockito.any())).thenThrow(new IOException());.

Still, no exception is thrown during test and it fails. WIll be super thankful for the help, cause I feel I miss something really simple and just cannot see it.

Comment: PrepareForTest should target the service, not the system class. https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System

Comment: @Compass thank you very much. I guess I was so frustrated I would't find it on my own. If you post this as an answer I will be able to upvote it and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System

> Normally you would prepare the class that contains the static methods (let's call it X) you like to mock but because it's impossible for PowerMock to prepare a system class for testing so another approach has to be taken. So instead of preparing X you prepare the class that calls the static methods in X!

Basically, we mock the class's use of the System class, rather than unmockable System class itself.

```
@PrepareForTest({Files.class})
```

An alternative, non-Powermock way to do this without mocking any system class would be to create a helper method, @Spy the original class, and mock that helper method specifically to throw the exception.

```
when(spy.doSomethingWithSystemClasses()).thenThrow(new Exception("Foo"));
```

Comment: I did not understand the solution. Can you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/66528552/10091625 please?